# Google Chrome asking for user ID and password when opening URL from IFrame

Tags: c#, asp.net, iframe

I am working on IFrame for the first time. The problem I am facing is that I am opening a URL on an IFrame, The URL opens correctly in IE or Microsoft Edge. However, when I open the same url from Google Chrome, it gives me a popup to enter userID and password to access the url. I dont understand why is this happenning.

**URL EXAMPLE:**
https://www.aaaa.com/aa/authenticate?token=4d3a30365e4e41d787e4&employeeid=300030743&section=tr&cmd=scheduledlist

**Code Used**

```
ViralURL = https://www.aaaa.com/aa/authenticate?token=4d3a30365e4e41d787e4&employeeid=300030743&section=tr&cmd=scheduledlist    
ViralURL = ViralURL .Replace("http:", "https:");
```

**HTML**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  if(document.getElementById("abc"))     
  {
   document.getElementById("abc").src="<%=ViralURL %>";
  }
</script>

<tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:Panel ID="aaIframe" runat="server">

                        <iframe id="abc" scrolling="auto" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" frameborder="0" vspace="0" hspace="0" style="overflow:visible; width:100%;height:650px;"></iframe>
                    </asp:Panel>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblError" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblURL" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                </td>
            </tr>
```

Comment: I imagine this has nothing to do with the code you've written and everything to do with the web server configuration hosting the URL you are trying to load. I suspect it's set up to use windows credentials.

Comment: it is loading properly with IE and EDGE.IF windows credentials were set up, then it should have asked in IE as well

Comment: Yes, you already stated that in your question. Look at the server configuration.